# What is the name of a particular architectural structure from a Gothic Church?

Tags: architecture, church

I'm sorry if this is not the right forum to ask such a question, but I'm interested in finding out the name of a particular structure from a 15th-Century Gothic Church that is located in Saschiz, Romania.

The structure is indicated by the red arrow in the picture below. I know that clerestory window is the name we give to a window above eye level, but what about those tiny, square-looking openings just under the roof? What is their name? What are they for?

The picture was obtained from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saschiz_fortified_church#/media/File:Biserica_fortificata_din_Saschiz.jpg).

[image]

Comment: This church seems to completely miss the point of gothic church architecture - that you can have many large windows.

Comment: @MCW yes, you're correct! Thank you.

Comment: @Jan It is supposed to be a fortified church. This church can be found in Saschiz, Romenia.

Comment: @Ricardo Maia I think the info that this church is located in Saschiz/Romania should be in the question.

Comment: @Jan you are correct! My oversight.

Comment: @MCW I got it from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saschiz_fortified_church#/media/File:Biserica_fortificata_din_Saschiz.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to "[Die Wehrkirchen in Siebenbürgen](https://digital.slub-dresden.de/en/workview/dlf/259895/170)" by George Oprescu, these are arrow slits (["Schießscharten"](https://digital.slub-dresden.de/en/workview/dlf/259895/171)). This is a feature that is rare for churches outside of Transsylvania, which probably contributed to this church (in Saschiz/Romania) being part of a [UNESCO world heritage site](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villages_with_fortified_churches_in_Transylvania).

Comment: Thank you sir! I thought the arrow slits were the vertical gaps on the bell tower on the side of church! Very good to know the square-shaped holes are also arrow-slits!

Comment: Actually I am neither 100% sure that "arrow slit" is the correct term nor that they were used for arrows rather than other projectiles (e.g. crossbow bolts or whatever small early firearms would shoot)

Comment: @Jan - Perhaps, but its sounds much better for a church than calling them "murder holes."

Comment: According to Mr. Oprescu, the church actually has (vertical) murder holes ("Gusslöcher") as well. Or are *these* holes called machicolations?

Comment: [The Germans' Gate in Metz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germans%27_Gate) has rounded artillery [loopholes](https://blog.stephens.edu/arh101glossary/?glossary=loophole) and square windows, as arrow slits are also sized to the weapon's business end.